# Access Denied some times on default.aspx page?

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise

I am getting "access denied" error some times for "Pages/default.aspx" and some times for different pages too. but if you refresh or type the page is showing properly.

I am not understanding where is the problem?

If it is "Access denied". It should show "Access denied" page all the time. But it is not happening that way.

Comment: Does your site use page output caching?  If so, you may have the wrong cache profile selected

Comment: 1) Do you have multiple front-end servers in the farm? 2) Do you have antivirus for SharePoint installed (specific to SharePoint, not the client on the servers).

Comment: You can use Fiddler to monitor the traffic between your browser and the server to see what content might be giving you the error (could be a resource the page is trying to load).

Comment: @DaveWise Where should I check the page output caching?

Comment: @JohnChapman I dont have 2 front-end servers.Now I stopped one server completely. Still getting same error. No anti Virus installed on servers.

Comment: Page output caching can be found under Site Settings - Site Collection Settings - Site Collection Output Cache Settings

Comment: @DaveWise Anonymous and Authenticated both are disabled. none checkboxes are selected..

Comment: Are you using SSL to deliver the site?  If yes, are you seeing any SCHANNEL errors in the system log?